# power bi: calculated columns dont appear in merge/append query

Tags: powerbi

why in power bi calculated columns do not appear in merging or appending two different tables? Is there any way to enable this thing? 
I am facing difficulties while merging two tables in which one of the table contains calculated columns.

Comment: Hoping I answered you in the other question.
Calculated columns do appear in merged queries. You might just have to check if it was expanded.

Answer (score 0):

Calculated columns doesn't appear in query editor. Try adding column in query editor itself if possible.

Comment: I tried adding columns in query editor but their value comes out to be null.

Comment: can you share the calculation you are trying to do, may be some data type issues.